# Fetch count of records created daily in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I need to create a  graph based on the records created  daily in the mongo  by the users.
I have a field to store the create date  in mongo  collection.
The ouput required is silimar to the following :

```
Date           Count
2014-01-01     12
2014-01-02     21
.
.
.
.
.
2014-01-30     90
```

I have already gone through various examples and read articles for the same.
This is  something similar to  Groupby in mysql.

Please help me with the query for the same.

Comment: Showing the actual document might help you. But you could otherwise have just looked at [SQL to aggregation mapping chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the official MongoDB documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing liberally from the MongoDB aggregation framework page at http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

db.records.aggregate(
  { $group : {
       _id : "date",
       itemsPerDate : { $sum : 1 }
  }}
);

Your mileage will vary based on language and document structure.

Answer (score 0):

Have a deep look into the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/). you are looking for the [`$group` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

```
db.test.aggregate({$group: {_id : "$Date", Count : {$sum: 1}}})
```